# Stopping Action Listener Queue

Tags: java

I Have this:

```
public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e) { ... }
public void actionPerformed2(ActionEvent e) { ... }
public void actionPerformed3(ActionEvent e) { ... }

JButton b = new JButton();

b.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed1);
b.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed2);
b.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed3);
```

> The code always executes action 3, then 2 and 1 in that order.

Is it possible to stop the execution of the queue without throwing a run time exception?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure, just add a flag whether further listeners should be executed and check it in the listener methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot stop it without using an `Exception`. If you look at the code in `JButton` which gets executed when its firing an `ActionEvent` (s.b.), you see that its just iterating in a for loop over a copy of the array of registered `ActionListeners`.
So you can try within the callback methods to unregister all `Actionlistener`s but this does not help since the loop uses a local copy. And you cannot increment the variable `i` from the callback neither.

```
protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
     // Dispatch a copy of the given ActionEvent in order to
     // set the source and action command correctly.
     ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(
         this,
         e.getID(),
         getActionCommand(),
         e.getWhen(),
         e.getModifiers());

     ActionListener[] listeners = getActionListeners();

     for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) //no way to prematurely terminate this loop 
       listeners[i].actionPerformed(ae);
 }
```

However you can use a common variable in your class to signal in your callback methods, that they should just return, but this would **not avoid their execution**, but rather execute code which just decides to prematurely return.